# Get sql.h error on MacOS 12 (Monterey) sqsrv and pdo_sqsrv drive installation

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I have macOS 12 Monterey, PHP 7.4. I would like to install sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv drives. However, I got the following error.

```
g++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/include/php/ext -std=c++11 -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootbnJKua/pdo_sqlsrv-5.9.0/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootbnJKua/pdo_sqlsrv-5.9.0/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/include/php -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/include/php/main -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/include/php/Zend -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/include/php/ext -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fstack-protector -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_dbh.cpp  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/pdo_dbh.o
    In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/pdo_dbh.cpp:24:
    In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/php_pdo_sqlsrv_int.h:23:
    In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/core_sqlsrv.h:41:
    In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/FormattedPrint.h:24:
    In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/xplat_winnls.h:24:
    In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/typedefs_for_linux.h:23:
    /private/tmp/pear/temp/pdo_sqlsrv/shared/xplat.h:30:10: fatal error: 'sql.h' file not found
    #include <sql.h>
             ^~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    make: *** [pdo_dbh.lo] Error 1
    ERROR: `make' failed
```

I also try 5.10.0-beta2 (pre-release)
[1]: https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/. But I still get the same error. Did I miss any steps or the release is not ready for macOS 12. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This may be helpful, even though I came across the issue while installing ODBC packages in Python in Monterey on an M1 Mac, as opposed to PHP.

Assuming that you have installed `unixodbc` via brew (`brew install unixodbc`), your compiler header files will be somewhere like:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/include
```

All, you need to do is adding this path to your CPPFLAGs during compiling. In my case in particular:

```
CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/include' pip install pyodbc
```

Comment: This worked for me: `CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/include' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/lib'  pip install pyodbc`

Comment: Tried same approach for nodejs. Getting `ld: library not found for -lodbc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was facing same error while installing `pyodbc`. This solution fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, MacOS Monterey 12.1 works with:

```sh
sudo CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/include' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/lib' pecl install pdo_sqlsrv sqlsrv
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the issue when installing sqlsrv on an M1 Mac (Ventura 13.2)